# How to disable built-in Wi-Fi and use only USB Wi-Fi card?

Tags: wireless, usb

The built-in Wi-Fi card in my laptop (Dell XPS M1330) is crap, pretty much. I have an Asus USB Wi-Fi card, which is significantly better and works fine.

What I'd like to do is disable the built-in Wi-Fi card.

Is there a way to do this without having to boot into BIOS each time I want to disable/enable the built-in wireless?

Here is the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:179d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
```

And here is the `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` output:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell XPS M1330 [1028:0209]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Doesn't your laptop have a button to switch wireless on and off?

Comment: @LnxSlck: Yes, but it disables all wireless capability including the USB wifi card.

Answer (score 81):

Add the following line to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

NetworkManager doesn't manage interfaces configured in the `interfaces` file. Replace `wlan0` with the interface you want to disable, if it's not the name of the built-in interface.

Then restart network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: It won't let me save because it's read-only?

Comment: @Matt Edit with `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`, add the line, save and exit (Ctrl+O, ENTER, Ctrl+X).

Comment: Works like charm..

Comment: In my case it was `wifi0` instead of `wlan0` (Lubuntu 16). Check `ifconfig` for the right device name.

Comment: Identifying the logical device name can get confusing.  `ifconfig` is absolutely no help in this.  Do a `sudo lshw -C network` to match the plain english descriptions to logical device name.  For example, the builtin on my Dell Lattitude running Mint is `wlp3s0` and the external wifi (usb) is `wlx9cefd5fcd694`.

Comment: After i did this, my CloudPath utility for connecting to eduroam wifi network did not see the USB wifi adapter.  The built in adapter is `wlp3s0` which is one of two, the USB being `wlxd45d649ce597` so I added iface wlp3s0 inet manual` and the `sudo service network-manager restart`,  Here is the CloudPath utility I am using on Ubuntu 18.04: https://it.ubc.ca/services/email-voice-internet/wireless-internet-access/wireless-internet-access-setup-documents#eduroam

Comment: FYI to all, this answer hasnt been updated since 2016. 
I couldnt find 'interfaces' in etc/network/ on Xubuntu 20.04. is it because of slight difference in OS or am i missing something else.
Only this answer worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1320155/327339

Comment: For Ubuntu 21.10 `network-manager` has been renamed `NetworkManager`
so last command would be `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Answer (score 30):

<s>I think the easiest way to do this is with `ifconfig`.</s>
EDIT 2021-03-02:
Apparently, [if you're still using ifconfig you're living in the past](https://ubuntu.com/blog/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past), so have a look at [Gabriel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320155/327339) below for an `ip` solution. Read below for the old `ifconfig` solution.

---

**`ifconfig` solution:**
Run

```
ifconfig
```

then look at which adapter you want to turn off, in my case `wlan1` is my internal wifi and `wlan2` is my usb wifi.
Then run

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
```

and it will turn off (type `ifconfig` to check, note that in the network manager the adapter still shows, but it is turned off). To turn it on again:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
```

and that's it.

Comment: How can I find if the adapter I want to disable/enable is `wlan1`, `wlan2` or something else?

Comment: `ifconfig` will tell you which adapters are there, most likely the lowest number will be your built-in adapter, but I think you should just try it to be sure.

Comment: It seems that `sudo lshw -C network` give a list of items whose 'logical name's are the ones to be used with `sudo ifconfig [logical name] up`.

Comment: Oh that does give a lot more information than `netstat` or `ifconfig`, nice!

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Network -> Wireless, the find your network name and click the ">" (greater-than symbol) at the far right edge.  Then click "Settings" in the lower-right corner, and ensure the "Wi-Fi" tab is selected.  The line "Device MAC address" will show both the h/w address and the network name (in parentheses).  The network name is the same as that shown by `ifconfig`

Comment: Actually, the above seems to reconnect. Look at the detail page in System Settings -> Network. Instead of `Wi-Fi` tab, go to `General` tab and uncheck `Automatically connect to this network when it is available`, as well as the `All users may connect...`.  This seems to keep the built-in card from connecting to wifi.

Comment: For me on 16.04 this causes the interface to disappear from `ifconfig` for a moment, but then it reappears and reconnects soon.

Comment: This didn't do anything

Comment: Note that I'm using your `ifconfig` answer to turn my adapters on and off, but `iwconfig` shows much more useful output to see which adapters are available, and what their connection speeds (`Bit Rate`), `Link Quality`, and `Signal level` values are. It also shows the ESSID of any network an adapter is connected to, as well as at what `Frequency` (ex: `Frequency:2.447 GHz`).

Comment: @GerhardBurger, apparently `ifconfig` is being deprecated and `ip link set` is what we are supposed to use now? See: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ifconfig-vs-ip. So, I added an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1320155/327339.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Thanks, very useful, I added a link at the top of my answer!

Answer (score 16):

To blacklist the module of your wireless card:

1. `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (or create a custom one)
2. Uncomment the module name that has a `#`  in the beginning of the line:

   ```
   blacklist eth1394
   ```
3. Save, run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot

To remove a module manually without rebooting:

```
sudo modprobe -r eth1394
```

Looses effect after reboot.

To load the module:

```
sudo modprobe eth1394
```

To see modules loaded:

```
sudo lsmod
```

Comment: If you wanted to blacklist eth1394 woudln't you _uncomment_ the line or add a new line ? Otherwise this is what I needed thanks!

Comment: For me this is the right solution. I'm on MX Linux and was confused, because doing `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` sets the interface down only for a few minutes, when checking back with `ifconfig` the interfaces was up again. So I added `blacklist iwlwifi` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and that's it. Btw. I don't need wifi at all.

Comment: @zayquan Thanks, not sure how i missed that

Comment: Did this and they still both appear.  Btw, does having the default original wifi card connect to the same wifi network as my superfast usb wifi adapter slow down the overall speed?

Comment: `lsmod` command doesn't require `sudo`. At least in Linux Mint 20.

Answer (score 13):

*This answer has been tested and works (at a minimum) on Ubuntu 20.04 with my BrosTrend 1200Mbps Wifi adapter. See my [BrosTrendWifiAdapterSoftware](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/BrosTrendWifiAdapterSoftware) repo here. See also [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321922/327339).*

### How to enable/disable networking (ethernet or wifi) devices, arbitrarily

> How to disable built-in wifi and use only USB wifi card?

1. Unplug your external USB wifi adapter.
2. Run `iwconfig` to see what your built-in adapter looks like. Mine shows `wlan0`. So, that is my built-in wifi adapter!
3. Now plug in your *external* USB wifi adapter and run `iwconfig` again to see which device just showed up. This new device showing up in `iwconfig` is what you just plugged in, so we can know it is the external USB wifi adapter. Mine shows `wlan3`.
4. Run the following to disable the internal wifi adapter, `wlan0`:

   ```bash
   # recommended (newer cmd)
   sudo ip link set wlan0 down
   # alternative (apparently an older cmd)
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
   ```
5. Done!
6. If you ever wanted to re-enable your internal wifi card, `wlan0` as we discovered above, run:

   ```bash
   # recommended (newer cmd)
   sudo ip link set wlan0 up
   # alternative (apparently an older cmd)
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```

### References:

1. [This `ifconfig` answer by Gerhard Burger](https://askubuntu.com/a/204536/327339)
2. **NOTE:** Apparently this `ip link set` command is intended to replace the older (and apparently/supposedly now-deprecated?) `ifconfig` cmd! See: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ifconfig-vs-ip --> in the sections "What's trending?" and "Enable and disable an interface".

### See also:

1. My other answer here: [How to disable built-in wifi and use only USB wifi card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wifi-and-use-only-usb-wifi-card/1321922#1321922).
2. [my answer] [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: "How can I create a virtual ethernet interface on a machine without a physical adapter?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad/593142#593142)

Comment: Thanks, this worked when the top answer did not. Upvoted.

Comment: what if iwconfig doesn't change after you plug in the usb device?

Comment: @jcollum, in that case it probably means you have a driver issue and need to install its driver. For example, [here are some of my GitHub repos for various WiFi drivers](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/BrosTrendWifiAdapterSoftware#all-of-my-wifi-adapter-repos).

Comment: hmm I did install the driver though https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000041287-how-to-install-ew-7811-ac600-ew-7822uac-in-linux-with-kernel-higher-than-v4-1

Comment: surprised this had no upvotes before I showed up, good answer

Comment: @jcollum, so did you figure out your problem and did my answer work for you? Why didn't `iwconfig` change for you before when plugging in the USB device?

Comment: Turned out my issue was my internal wireless card had no antennas plugged in. Now, how that stopped the USB wireless card from working is a mystery, but that's what happened. It worked with no issues once I fixed the hardware issue.

Answer (score 7):

Connect the USB Wi-Fi dongle and disable the internal Wi-Fi adapter as below:

1. Identify your adapter's name by:

   ```
   ip link | grep wl
   ```

   or:

   ```
   ifconfig | grep wl
   ```

   The adapter's name should be something similar to `wlp2s0` or `wlan0`, in which the digits in the names could be any number in your case.
2. Disable the adapter by:

   ```
   sudo ip link set wlp2s0 down
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
   ```

   In your case replace the adapter's name respectively.

This will ensure that only the USB Wi-Fi adapter is active even though the internal Wi-Fi driver will still be active.

---

**ALTERNATIVELY**

Disable the internal Wi-Fi driver module:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm
```

This will ensure that only the USB Wi-Fi dongle is active.

Comment: sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm worked for me.. but how can I make it persistent after reboot.. please help..

Comment: make it persistent by typing `sudo modprobe -b iwlmvm`

Comment: modprobe command is so cool. I was wondering how to identify which driver module my laptop is using for wifi. In my case, I might not have "iwlmvm" as the wifi driver's name. How to identify the real name?

Answer (score 5):

Most laptops these days have Intel wireless cards, which you can very easily disable using the command:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

or disable and blacklist permanently using:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi; sudo modprobe -b iwlwifi
```

I do this with my laptop to use my high-gain TP-Link adapter instead of the internal Wi-Fi card.

Answer (score 4):

The built in wifi is Broacom's BCM4312, which uses the proprietary STA driver. So, no need to blacklist anything in your particular case, just deactivate the driver, using the Additional Drivers utility.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that Trend-tech, who makes the BrosTrend AC1200 2.4GHz/5GHz WiFi adapter [which I document in my repo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/BrosTrendWifiAdapterSoftware), recommends the following.

From: https://deb.trendtechcn.com/advanced/internal-adapters/:

> ### Internal adapters
>
> Normally it should be possible for many wifi adapters to coexist, both internal and external ones. Unfortunately some of our customers have reported that they had connectivity issues that were resolved when they disabled their internal adapter. This may be caused by a bug in the Linux kernel, in wpa_supplicant, in network-manager or elsewhere. It’s probably not caused by our driver, as these problems happen with other USB adapters as well.
>
> To temporarily disable your internal adapter and see if it makes things better, please open a terminal and follow the procedure below. Note that for Raspberry Pi devices, [this procedure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3?answertab=active#tab-top) is recommended instead.
>
> The following command shows the names of the modules (drivers) for your wifi adapters. The module for our adapters is named `8812au`, `88x2bu` or `8821cu`. The module for Intel adapters is named `iwlwifi`. For Atheros it’s `ath9k`, etc.
>
> ```bash
> ls -d /sys/module/cfg80211/holders/*/drivers | cut -d/ -f6
> # Example output:
> 88x2bu
> iwlwifi
> ```
>
> In the following commands, replace `iwlwifi` with the module that you want to blacklist:
>
> ```bash
> sudo -i
> echo "blacklist iwlwifi" > /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
> update-initramfs -u
> reboot
> ```
>
> After rebooting, the internal adapter should be disabled. Also, if you have more than one USB wifi adapters, remove the additional ones. Check if things work better that way.
>
> If you ever need to remove the blacklist, use the following commands:
>
> ```bash
> sudo -i
> rm /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
> update-initramfs -u
> reboot
> ```

In a personal email to me from their Linux support team (who actually does seem to know what they are talking about, which is awesome!), they also said:

> The network manager `nm-connection-editor` dialog (run that from a
> terminal to see which one I mean) has a "Device" combo box, where you
> can set a MAC address in order to limit one wifi connection to a
> specific adapter, or you can leave it empty if you want it to work with
> any adapter.
>
> So normally there's no need to disable the internal adapter at all.

That also looks pretty relevant and does seem to work.

### See also:

1. My other answer here: [How to disable built-in wifi and use only USB wifi card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wifi-and-use-only-usb-wifi-card/1320155#1320155).

Comment: This works flawlessly for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I usually physically remove the internal card. this is usually a mini PCI-e card with 1 or 2 antenna connections. the antenna connections can be carefully lifted up and they disconnect without any fuss. there will usually be 1 Phillips screw holding the card in place. once the screw is removed, lift the back of the card and slide it out of it's edge connector. i usually fold electrical (vinyl) tape over the antenna wire connectors and push the screw through the electrical tape. then re-install the screw (thus holding the antenna wires in their former place). this solves the problem of an undesired internal wireless quite nicely.

note that some cards also include Bluetooth and this procedure removes such Bluetooth as well.

also note that with usb radios, the radio must be turned off before unplugging the radio. on some operating systems, the system crashes if the radio is unplugged before being turned off in the operating system (while still booted).

Answer (score 1):

Network manager has a little-known command-line interface called `nmcli`. If all you want is for the network manager not to manage the interface, you can run:

```
nmcli device set <interface-name> managed no
```

To list the possible interface names, use:

```
ip link
```

If that list doesn't give you enough information to work out which one you want to disable, you can use:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer was strictly "How to disable" but for most users like me who have searched this and haven't taken a networking course before ( or in my case 10 years ), the easiest way to "Get this thing working on my Ubuntu" is to just click the wifi icon at the top right of the screen and look for your usb wifi-receiver and connect it to a network.  Make sure it connects so you know the drivers are working, and then disconnect the old one ( probably connected through pci ).

If you bought your usb wireless card through a third party vendor, there's a 99% chance that the card will not show up under the name of that vendor, ie "Joes Hardware on Amazon" or "Brostrend" or whatever.  It will most likely be the name of the actual hardware inside the casing of the thing you bought, and that will probably be Realtek or Intel or something.  So look for one of those names in the dropdown wifi menu.

If you need to find the name of your built in wifi, just run:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and look for:
description: Wireless interface
and
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
and
product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]

That's the one you want to disbale in the dropdown menu.  Whether or not your system will keep the old crappy wifi disabled after you reboot your machine is another story.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of this on Ubuntu 20.04 and none of it worked. When I tried the modprobe solution network manager simply created a new device! So finally I simply unplugged the tiny little wifi card from the motherboard and that worked. If you can't solve it in software try this hardware solution.

Comment: OK there was an unfortunate side effect: the wifi card is also the Bluetooth card so I have also disabled Bluetooth. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted to connect a USB Wifi card to my home network.

Under Ubuntu 20.04 the solution is to modify the "interface-name" parameter in the network connection file.
Under Ubuntu 20.04 all the network connection files containing which network card (WIFI or Ethernet) is assigned to which network are located under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
The parameter "interface-name" is at the top of connection file

As an exemple here are the network connections I have on my laptop

```
ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
-rw------- 1 root root 350 oct.  15 17:38 wiseDom.nmconnection
-rw------- 1 root root 350 oct.  15 16:44 wiseDom.nmconnection-old
-rw------- 1 root root 364 avril  3  2022 WIZEDOMWIFI.nmconnection
-rw------- 1 root root 350 oct.  13 19:18 WIZEDOMWIFI.nmconnection-old
```

On my laptop the name of the on-board WIFI adapter (listed with usr/sbin/ifconfig) is: wlp3s0
and the name of the USB WIFI adapter is: wlx54af97552ea2

Following on my exemple here is what was assigned to the "interface-name" parameter in my old connection file:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wiseDom.nmconnection-old |grep "interface-name"
interface-name=wlp3s0
```

and to use the USB WIFI card (wlx54af97552ea2) I modified it to be:

```
interface-name=wlx54af97552ea2
```