# Turning down wireless button turns down external usb wireless. Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, lubuntu, eeepc

I searched in other topics without luck.

I've got an Eeepc 1000h and lubuntu 12.10.

When I turn down my laptop wireless capability (FN+F2) it turns down the usb external antenna as well.

**I don't want to exclude for ever my internal wireless** (as suggested in other answers) I would like to turn down wireless with its button leaving USB-external-wifi ON. As it is intended to be.

Any chance to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

**rfkill list all**

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: post output of `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Added rfkill in the first message. Cheers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wifi-and-use-only-usb-wifi-card

Comment: Not a duplicate. I red it before posting. The solution given to the user was disable via terminal the internal wlan card which I'm trying to avoid. I would like to enable/disable wireless via keyboard buttons (FN+F2) -as it's supposed to be working- KEEPING external-usb-wifi active. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some infos.

With

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower off
```

it turns off both. Anyway in 20 seconds it turns on automatically. (and the led stays on, btw)

The only solution I can get by myself is to turn it down via BIOS. What an ugly workaroud :-(

Expert needed here!

Answer (score 0):

Like exposed in another answer I actually use this workaround.

Add the following line to `/etc/network/interfaces:`

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

Then Restart. This disables internal Wifi. (or whatever you call wlan0).

If I need my internal wifi working again then I command out it with `#` and restart.

This is a very bad thing, but it works. Now, I can't believe in this community there isn't anyone that can't fix this to make it goes as it is supposed to do.

In Windows it's easy and immediate. Why couldn't be like that in Ubuntu?