# Bricked laptop in Ubuntu 12.04 ; with wifi adaptor

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I am using a *Asus laptop* with Ubuntu 12.04.

My internal wifi adapter stopped working. So I put in a *usb adapter*. But then I had two adapters both trying to connect to the same network, from Which neither can connect. They keep knocking each other offline.

So after doing some research I was went into  `etc/network/interfaces` and changed it. So that `wlan0` was *manual start instead of auto start*. At that point I tried to reboot, and at the splash screen I got a message that the computer was *waiting network connection*. After a minute or two, that changes to *continue booting without correct network configuration*. And that's it, it just sits there, doing nothing.

So I boot up with my live CD, and used `gksudo nautilus`, and went back into the *Operating system filesystem* (not the filesystem on the cd), and corrected the changes made in the interfaces file,then reboot. Still the same. `continue booting without correct network configuration`, error msg. I have went back and verified the corrections I made were accurate against the CD filesystem.

> *So what is happening ?*
>
> *How did I mess up that bad by just adding `iface wlan0 inet manual` (
>   from those instructions I found
>   [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wifi-and-use-only-usb-wifi-card?)
>   ) ?*

I decided that was easier than blacklisting, because well it just seemed easier. Just my luck.

Here are the results of some terminal commands, I got these from booting onto the Live CD. I've also had two adapters plugged in together with no problem, but it kept saying *wlan0 connected* , *wlan1 disconnected* etc. Until I either get this fixed, or reinstall for all practical purposes it is bricked.

I do have the <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> combination, I didn't do that to start with because that also turns off the *USB adapter* . After turning wifi off, and rebooting still the same thing, here's the results leaving off the *Wired ethernet* other than just to mention it. Also you will notice that the wireless adapters are both the same brand, which is unusual.

```
lspci -nn  
02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Ralink Corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]


lsusb  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter


sudo lshw -c network  
* network 
description: Wireless interface
product RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
Vendor Ralink Corp
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 00
serial: 08:ed:b9:6a:0f
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm mse pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.8.0-23-generic 
firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:17 memory:de800000-de80ffff

*-network 
description: Wireless interface
Physical id: 1
bus info: usb@2:1.2
logical name: wlan1
serial: 7c:dd:90:12:d2:f2
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configeration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.8.0-23-generic firmware=0.29 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

*-network
description: Ethernet interface
pysical id: 0
logical name: eth0

sudo rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
                     Soft blocked: yes
                     Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
             Soft blocked: yes
             hard blocked: yes
2: phy1 Wireless LAN
             Soft blocked: yes
             Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I expect there's a keyboard combination (<alt-F3> on mine) to disable the internal wifi. That might have been a better choice, though I've had multiple wifi adapters plugged in with no ill effects, so I don't know what caused your original problem

Comment: Your laptop is not [bricked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_(electronics); it is a software not a firmware or hardware problem.