# Disable network permanently

Tags: networking

I want to install an ubuntu System to an USB Stick and if I boot this, I don't want it to connect to the internet. Is there a Way to archieve this? I tried

```
sudo ifconfig eth2 down
```

But it is up again at the next restaret

Comment: well the easiest is probably to just unplug the cable then you wont connect to the internet...

Answer (score 1):

#### Method #1 - from NetworkManager's Applet

Try disabling the wireless networking under the Network Applet that's accessible from under the icons in the upper right of your desktop.

[image: ss #!]

**NOTE:** The networking applet's icon looks like a triangle wedge. The image above is pointing to is as arrow #1. If you click it you should see a menu slide out from where you can disable wireless permanently, arrow #2.

#### Method #2 - /etc/network/interfaces

From the file `/etc/network/interfaces` you can specify that NetworkManager shouldn't control the `wlan0` interface. To do so simply add this line to the above mentioned file:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

Then restart NetworkManager:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

#### References

- [How to disable built-in wifi and use only USB wifi card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032/how-to-disable-built-in-wifi-and-use-only-usb-wifi-card)

Answer (score 1):

Add `sudo ifconfig eth2 down` in /etc/rc.local file so at login it will be down.

Answer (score -1):

Just unplug your cable.

```
sudo ifdown eth2
```

Try it...