# Ralink RT2870 network adapter

Tags: wireless, 16.04, ralink

I just purchased a network adapter which according to the driver CD is a RT2870 (It isn't written on the adapter). I've installed other things using commands before but the instructions on the readme file that came with it are quite confusing.

Has anybody made this network adapter work successfully in Ubuntu? I'd really appreciate some simple step by step instructions of how to make this work.

Comment: The driver *rt2800usb* is built in to Ubuntu 16.04 by default. Did you try just inserting it and seeing if it connects? What do these terminal commands tell us? `lsusb` and also: `dmesg | grep rt2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me:
(I found this at [How to install RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641724/how-to-install-rt2870-rt3070-wireless-driver)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install mt7601-sta-dkms
```

Btw, that last line took like 5-10 minutes to complete, at times it looked line it was hung. So be patient. After the last line it complete, then you must reboot for the adapter and driver to work properly. if you don't reboot, you will will waste time trying to figure out why it doesn't work as expected.

Regards . . .