# I lost my driver for USB WiFi adapter Ralink RT3070

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink

I had my Sveon SNT1015, having chipset Ralink RT2830/RT3070, up and running nicely in my Ubuntu 16.10. The proper driver got installed automatically at SysOp installation time.

Then I tried to install de driver that came with a new Dual band WiFi adapter and somehow, while following the instructions to compile and install the new driver, the driver for RT3070 got erased or damaged. The driver for the new device did not compile (As Usual when I try with drivers that come with hardware) but now, I lost the driver that was working perfectly for my old RT3070 / Sveon SNT1050.

I have tried to install the linux driver that come with the Sveon, but Guess..! It won't compile or make either.

The RT3070 must be supported in the Ubuntu installation because the device was detected and configured perfectly at Ubuntu installation time.

IS there a simple way to download and install the driver that was originally installed without having to squeeze my brains trying to make and install the driver from scratch???

I get the following output form lsusb and dmesg:

```
Ubu1:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 15a4:1336 Afatech Technologies, Inc. SDHC/MicroSD/MMC/MS/M2/CF/XD Flash Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


Ubu1:~$ dmesg
(...)
[    1.410551] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070
[    1.410554] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.410557] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[    1.410559] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Ralink
[    1.410561] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[    1.428901] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.546309] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=15a4, idProduct=1336
[    1.546312] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.546314] usb 2-1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[    1.546316] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Generic   
[    1.546318] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000006
[    1.688747] ata2.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.688758] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.688876] ata1.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.688886] ata1.01: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.691602] ata2.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDT721010SLA360, ST6OA3AA, max UDMA/133
[    1.691605] ata2.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.693793] ata1.00: ATA-11: KINGSTON SUV400S37240G, 0C3J96R9, max UDMA/133
[    1.693796] ata1.00: 468862128 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.694123] ata1.01: HPA detected: current 1953508719, native 1953525168
[    1.694125] ata1.01: ATA-8: ST31000528AS, CC38, max UDMA/133
[    1.694127] ata1.01: 1953508719 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.696679] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.696737] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.701714] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.702104] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      KINGSTON SUV400S 96R9 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.724674] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.740847] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB/224 GiB)
[    1.740848] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
(...) etc. etc.
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Thanks for your quick answer Heynnema and Elder Geek
Here is the result of your requested commands:

```
Ubu1:~$ **modinfo rt2800usb**
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2870.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 USB Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     79C8FF0D61161719C1D2E53
alias:          usb:vF201p5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0254d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApF511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApD522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApC522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA512d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0078d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0069d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0053d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p004Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p004Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v08B9p1197d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18E8p6259d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB29d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB24d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05A6p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v100Dp9032d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0169d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0168d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0615d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0605d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp094Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148FpF101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v06F8pE036d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0602d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0600d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp14A1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18C5p0008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0042d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0150d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0148d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p012Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3401d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3400d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3399d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3340d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3322d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3284d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3262d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17A7d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1761d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1760d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p166Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E0Bp9041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E0Bp9031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C11d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C08d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3073d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p724Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A13d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C21d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0253d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0241d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v057Cp8501d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5372d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2182d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2181d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2180d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2126d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2104d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp23F6d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp1800d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp1801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A42d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A22d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C23d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C22d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C20d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C19d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C15d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3365d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3329d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17E8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3421d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0067d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3573d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pED19d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp094Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0021d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0020d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7733d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148FpF301d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17ADd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17BCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p7733d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0284d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p0A07d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0068d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0066d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0065d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0062d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0170d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0079d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p002Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0944d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v167Bp4001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p179Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0764d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0761d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0744d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0165d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0163d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0050d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp8070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p20DDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApB511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp945Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p343Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3418d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3416d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p5257d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0283d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0282d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0280d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0025d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v157Ep3013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v157Ep300Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0324d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0323d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0302d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0164d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0153d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApB522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA703d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA702d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA701d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA618d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap8522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7512d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap6618d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0060d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p005Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0051d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0048d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0047d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0042d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0040d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0039d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v129Bp1828d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04E8p2018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1A32p0304d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pED06d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019p5201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p200Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0011d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp000Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp000Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20B8p8888d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75pA200d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p899Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p870Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p821Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p6899d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3871d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3820d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v100Dp9031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0166d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0164d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0163d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0162d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0078d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0077d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p0031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0948d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0947d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0945d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p000Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0009d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9709d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9708d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9707d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9706d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9705d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9703d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9702d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9701d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp14A9d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp1480d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7722d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7718d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7717d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7711d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p4085d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE9pB307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07FAp7712d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3317d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C16d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C15d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C13d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C11d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18C5p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp003Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp002Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01FDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01A8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01EEd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01A2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p016Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p015Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0158d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p00E8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp935Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp935Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp825Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp825Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp815Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp805Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp8053d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3321d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3305d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3273d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3247d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1761p0B05d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1784d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1742d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1732d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1731d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0740d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15C5p0008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C2Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C28d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C27d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C23d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C07d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C06d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2210d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1482p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

Ubu1:~$ **grep -i rt2800usb /etc/modprobe.d/***
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist rt2800usb
```

Comment: In `terminal` do a `modinfo rt2800usb`, and a `grep -i rt2800usb /etc/modprobe.d/*` and edit your question to show us the results.

Comment: @ElderGeek please see my answer.

Comment: Close vote retracted. While related, not a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641724/how-to-install-rt2870-rt3070-wireless-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While installing another driver, the install process disabled the standard RT2830/RT3070 driver. This can be seen when we do the following:

```
$ modinfo rt2800usb
```

This shows us that the driver still exists.

```
$ grep -i rt2800usb /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist rt2800usb
```

it shows us that the rt2800usb kernel driver is blacklisted, which means it'll never load.

The fix is to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and remove the line, or comment out the line, containing `blacklist rt2800usb`.

In `terminal` type `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, delete or comment out the line, save and quit gedit, and you should reboot, and try your device again.

Comment: Thanks so much Heynnema. Simple and elegant solution. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks to ElderGeek and everyone else who answered. Your suggestions did not work but I learned things from it. Your altruistic help makes the world a bit better every day.

Comment: +1 Bravo. Well done. Nice job figuring out it was blacklisted. I got pulled away to repair a dryer. (One must keep the wife happy or life becomes painful.) ;-) Close vote retracted