# How to disable a wifi adapter

Tags: wireless

I have two Wifi adapters connected to my desktop: a PCI express TP-Link adapter, which is crap, and a USB Netgear adapter. I don't feel like manually taking out the PCI-E adapter, so how can I set the USB one as the default, and disable the internal one?

Comment: please edit your question to include the result of `lshw -c net`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rfkill`

First, do `rfkill list`
This will show you the names of your interfaces. Then you can do `rfkill block <adapterindex>` and that interface will be blocked. You can unblock again with `rfkill unblock <adapterindex>`

For example, my `rfkill list` gives:
my-lat wilhelm # rfkill list

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So I could run `rfkill block 0` or `rfkill block 1`

You can add these commands to `/etc/rc.local` so they will be run on every boot.

For more information see `man rfkill`

Comment: How do I know which one is which? When I run rfkill list, I get this: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
7: phy7: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Sorry about the crappy formatting.

Comment: That's okay. for future reference you can enclose such things in `.
You could try removing the USB dongle and running it again. The index shouldn't change.

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus This question being marked as duplicate and your answer not being on the linked question, please add your answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168032).

Comment: Note that in my case blocking `phy0` blocked *both* the internal wifi card and the USB dongle, though.