# Problem using WiFi on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS with USB wifi adapter (Zebronics USB wifi adapter)

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I am new to linux and currently using Ubuntu Budgie(Dual Boot with windows 7). I am unable to use wifi. Have a look at the following Condition.
Wifi Adapter model - "ZEB-USB300WF"
Ubuntu Budgie version - 20.04.3 LTS. Kernel version -5.11.0-37-generic.
Can anyone please check are the drivers for the usb adapter installed or not, as i tried installing the drivers once.
Chipset is RTL8192EU.

**Output of "lsusb" :**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:c342 Suyin Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here RTL8192EU is my usb wifi adapter.

**Output of "rfkill list all" :**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

PS : I tried "rfkill unblock all" it doesnt work.

**Output of "lshw -c network"**

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx1cbfceeb3cb3
       serial: 1c:bf:ce:eb:3c:b3
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192eu driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

**Output of "inxi -N":**

```
Network:   Device-1: Ralink RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe driver: rt2800pci 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 
           Device-3: Realtek RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: rtl8192eu
```

**Output of "iwconfig":**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      
wlx1cbfceeb3cb3  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not- 
Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**Output of "lsmod | grep 8192eu":**

```
8192eu               1351680  0
cfg80211              888832  3 8192eu,rt2x00lib,mac80211
```

[image: This is the condition when the Usb adapter is not plugged, I am unable to off Airplane mode at this stage.]

[image: This is the condition when I plugged the usb wifi adapter.]

Please help me to access wifi using usb wifi adapter.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What kernel version? What have you tried? What errors or symptoms do you have? This needs to be clear not buried in a pile of other stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install WiFi Driver rtl8192?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855668/how-to-install-wifi-driver-rtl8192)

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. Sentences in all capital letters are regarded as shouting, infantile and rude. Adjust accordingly if you want readers to take you seriously.

Comment: @David Ubuntu version - 20.04.3 LTS.  Kernel version -5.11.0-37-generic. I have tried installing drivers from github but i think i messed up and dont know where do i stand now. i dont know whats the problem. why the wifi isnt working. And sorry for the above mess , I will try to keep things clean hereafter ,Thank you.

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS alongside windows 7 on a HP laptop. And trying to access wifi through usb wifi adapter. I have tried various things and i think i messed up. I will be glad if anyone can help me to solve this mess.I will provide you with every information you need. I apologize for the mistakes i made and Thank you for pointing the mistakes .I need to learn a lot.

Comment: @manish-vaishnav If you think you've messed up driver installation, here's how you can properly remove it (you would have to adjust commands for your RTL8192EU): https://askubuntu.com/a/1182246/928088 And once removed, here's how you could you install drivers for RTL8192EU: https://askubuntu.com/a/1212527/928088 Thanks.

Comment: @Jags Thank you , but how do i know that the driver is properly installed or not ? Is there any command to check this ? I dont know if it was properly installed or not

Comment: @manish-vaishnav you can check whether module is loaded or not by: `lsmod | grep 8192eu`. Edit your question and post the results. Also, how did you install the drivers? I would suggest that: (1) If you have working internet access (either wired or through phone tethering), and (2) Driver you've installed is not working, then there's no harm in properly removing it and installing it again.

Comment: @Jags I have posted the output of "lsmod | grep 8192eu". Please suggest what to do next. Thank you

Comment: Can you remove the internal wifi adapter?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Sorry ,wont be able to do changes to hardware.Can you please suggest something else. Thanks.

Comment: `rfkill list` shows your `phy1` wireless is "`Hard blocked: yes`" - there's a Hardware switch, probably among/above the function keys.

Comment: @waltinator I have a function key to on/off Airplane mode . When i press the key ,it shows Hardware Airplane mode on.

Comment: I have no other suggestion but I know the hard block signal is passed through the internal wifi

Comment: @Jeremy31 Oh, But my usb adapter works perfectly in Windows 7 alongside. There is no such problem. I have posted two screenshot please do have a look if you can figure out something more. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to each and everyone for investing your time. Kudos to Open source community.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem is solved.
My Usb wifi Adapter was hard blocked by internal wifi card.
I was able to fix this with the help of this article.
[Wifi Dongle hard blocked by wifi card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741379/wifi-dongle-hard-blocked-by-wifi-card)

For removing module of the internal wifi adapter do the following

Get the kernel driver name by running

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

Take the name in the line "Kernel driver in use:". Make sure that it is the correct device (the wifi card and not e.g. the ethernet card). In my case it was rt2800pci.

Then either remove it for testing temporarily using

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
```

or permanentely by adding it to the blacklist

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```