# Switch between onboard wifi and usb wifi

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I'm looking for a way to easily disable the onboard wifi and use a USB wifi card when needed, for example when single is low from the onboard.

So, I found the rfkill command which looked perfect, however when I use it to disable the onboard wifi, it turns off all wifi.

Although, the rfkill list shows the onbard as blocked and the usb as NOT blocked I still can't use the usb and its greyed out in network manager. Also on the menu bar, enable wifi is unticketed.

Anyone know why this is? Or what I can use for a substitute?

Thanks

Comment: Why not connect in the NM the device you want to connect? Why disable the device?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/168032/396228